# Emulador Android não starta

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova

Estou fazendo um *projeto* `Android` com `ionic` e `cordova` mas o `emulador` não está funcionando.

Já olhei tudo e não encontro o erro.

O `emulador` simplesmente não abre.

Obs.: Estou aprendendo ainda.

Criei uma `AVD` com nome `Android` e fiz no `node`:

```
cordova emulate --target=Android android
```

Minha AVD lista:

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 10.9.0 (x64) and npm.

C:\Windows\System32>android list avd
Available Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: Android
  Device: Nexus 4 (Google)
    Path: C:\Users\Carlos\.android\avd\Android.avd
  Target: Android 8.0.0 (API level 26)
 Tag/ABI: default/x86
    Skin: 768x1280
  Sdcard: 200M

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Segue a compilação:

```
D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\node\cordova\ionic\Carcleo>cordova emulate --target=Android android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\sdk\Android\andoid-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_9md489uzh4m9h1sp026y6n5p6.run(D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\node\cordova\ionic\Carcleo\platforms\android\app\build.gradle:143)
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningDebug
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:cdvBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
46 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 45 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\node\cordova\ionic\Carcleo\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Trabalhos\Mobile\sdk\Android\andoid-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
Waiting for emulator to start...
```

Comment: quais são as especificações do seu pc ?  RAM, processador, placa de video etc ?
O android studio não rada muito bem  em pc's com menos de 8gb de ram  e tem alguns problemas com processadores intel . Você também pode debugar seu projeto conectando seu Smartphone ao pc

Comment: Hum, talvez seja esse o problema: Core 2 DUO 2GB com 4 MB RAM placa de vídeo Onboard. É um Acer 5920-6080 de 10 anos atrás. Em minha última tentativa até abriu uma outra janela do prompt, mas ficou ali parada e não exibia informação alguma

Comment: Pois é pode ser uns dos motivos do ADB estar demorando a carregar, infelizmente o  android studio consome muita memoria em  si, e  o  Android Emulator consome mais pelas configurações do seu pc pode até ser que venha a rodar, porem vai  ficar travando

Comment: Eu NÃO instalei o Android Studio. Apenas na sequencia: node, cordova, ionic Então, após instalar todas as dependências para rodar o emulador través do SDK Manager.exe. Gerei ois pacotes com o comando ionic start Carcleo blank então Rodei o comando cordova emulate --target=Android android e então a mágica começou. Porém, o emulador não incia.

Comment: @sam. Desculpe, não entendi! O que você quis dizer exatamente? Eu tenho várias perguntas mal formuladas aqui no fórum ou essa pergunta está mal formulada? O que realmente você quis dizer? E, à propósito, você teria alguma consideração a fazer para melhorar as respostas acima dadas para essa pergunta? Bom Dia!

Comment: Ok, entendi agora. Mas por enquanto o problema continua. Por isso ainda não marquei como resolvida! Mas obrigado pela orientação!

Comment: Tente executar o comando: cordova run android --emulator